# Laravel/Lighthouse - Resolve to an external API

Tags: php, laravel, soap, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I have a setup that uses laravel and lighthouse to create a graphql setup. I've gone through the tutorials on lighthouses page and it's worked great. In my use case, however, i'm looking to simplify the use of an xml Soap API using it.

I can't find in the documentation how to do this other than creating "resolvers", which i've managed to do. However these are set to fields..? So in order to return the correct information from the other api i'd have to do one for each field?

I'm getting a little lost.

Simply put, i just need to ask:

How do i plug in an external api so when i make a call with graphql it returns information from the api?

Comment: You need to make a GraphQl data type for all of your API's data points and define all of the fields. Then create your GraphQl endpoints which corresponds to your other API. 
There are currently no tool for Lighthouse to convert XML SOAP schema to a GraphQL schema. 
There should be some tools out there which can do this for Node. You can use that and then get the generated schema file and use it to setup Lighthouse.

You can also create your own tool. Here I would recommend creating a custom directive to do this. This might be the best way if you plan on updating you SOAP API in the future.

Comment: I did a little digging and figured out a way to do it. Thank you very much for the insight as well. It's appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i ended up using lighthouses built-in artisan function to create a custom resolver:

```
php artisan lighthouse:query
```

The file that is created from this in the graphql folder in the root of laravel allows me to input and output what i need correctly. I'll basically be using this file to do the calls and returning the response.

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: If this is resolved. Remember to mark your answer as the answer.

Comment: My apologies on that. I had to wait a day and completely forgot about it.